# Unresponsive GCP VM after suspend/resume - corrupted Boot Disk or DHCP config

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I recently suspended a VM in GCP.
After a few days, I resumed it, but I can't connect the instance in any way.

With a `ping` command pointing to the external IP, I obtain no response. Sending an HTTP request using a web browser doesn't work either, of course.

If I try connecting using SSH (either with the `gcloud` or the browser window), I get a connection timeout (Putty) or a `Code: 4003 Reason: failed to connect to backend`. I did try to add explicitly the SSH public key again editing to the VM setup. Also, I have a VM for a different environment which I never suspended, and that has no issued to connect.

I checked the Firewall rules, everything seems to be ok.

If I enable and connect to the serial console I see it's constantly logging these weird messages:

```
Mar 23[28087280.507763] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
 05:41:56 xxx[28087280.515939] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
 dhclient[600]: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 [28087280.527691] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
interval 8
Mar [28087280.535079] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
23 05:41:57 xxx dhclient[600]: DHCPREQUEST of 10.xxx.xxx.xxx on eth0 to 255.255.2[28087280.547472] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
55.255 port 67
[28087280.555395] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
Mar 23 05:41:57 xxx dhclient[600]: DHCPOFFER of 10.xxx.xxx.xxx from 169.xxx.xxx.xxx[28087280.567655] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
54
Mar 23 05:41[28087280.575244] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
:57 xxx dhclient[600]: DHCPACK of 10.xxx.xxx.xxx from 169.xxx.xxx.xxx
Mar 23 05:[28087280.710564] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
41:57 xxx dhc[28087280.717131] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
lient[600]: DHCP[28087280.724725] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
DECLINE on eth0 [28087280.731449] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
to 255.255.255.2[28087280.738646] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
55 port 67
Mar [28087280.745723] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
23 05:41:57 hoc-[28087280.752348] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
qa dhclient[600][28087280.759874] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
: DHCPDISCOVER o[28087280.766707] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
n eth0 to 255.25[28087280.773666] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
5.255.255 port 6[28087280.780721] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
7 interval 4
Ma[28087280.787709] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
r 23 05:41:57 ho[28087280.794742] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
c-qa dhclient[60[28087280.801786] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
0]: DHCPREQUEST [28087280.808534] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
of 10.xxx.xxx.xxx on[28087280.815978] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
 eth0 to 255.255[28087280.822758] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
.255.255 port 67[28087280.829765] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device

Mar 23 05:41:57 xxx dhclien[28087280.963410] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
t[600]: DHCPOFFER of 10.xxx.xxx.xxx from 169.xxx.xxx.xxx
Mar 23 05:41:57 xxx dhc[28087280.975106] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
lient[600]: DHCP[28087280.982881] sd 0:0:1:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
ACK of 10.xxx.xxx.xxx from 169.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I've seen a few threads where the SSH is messed up, but this seems to be an error of some sort with the Boot disk, or maybe with a DHCP configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is going through this same issue, I now solved it by executing the `RESET` operation on my VM.

After struggling for quite a lot of hours trying to figure out (unsuccessfully) a suitable solution for this, I think this will be the simpler solution, especially keeping in mind that my VM came from a suspended state.